# Is there a injective/surjective function for $f:[-2,3] \rightarrow [0,1] $

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is there a injective function for $f:[-2,3] \rightarrow [0,1] $ which isn't surjective and the other way is there a surjective function for $f:[-2,3] \rightarrow [0,1] $ which isn't injective? Hope somebody can help.

Comment: These two interval are homeomorphic..

Answer (score 4):

(1). Injective but not surjective

Take $$f(x)=\frac{1}{7}x+\frac{3}{7}$$

Clearly, this function is injective since $$f(x)=f(y) \implies \frac{1}{7}x+\frac{3}{7}=\frac{1}{7}y+\frac{3}{7} \implies \frac{1}{7}x=\frac{1}{7}y \implies x=y$$

Also, this function is not surjective because there is no $x$ such that $f(x)=0$. ($-3$ is not in the domain of the function)

(2). Surjective but not injective.

Take $f(x)=\frac{1}{4}x+\frac{1}{2}$ for $-2 \le x \le 2$ and $f(x)=3-x$ for $2 \le x \le 3$.

Clearly this function is surjective - to make $f(x)=k$, take $-2 \le x=4k-2 \le 2$.

Also, this function is not injective - $f(4k-2)=f(3-k)$, so for $k \not= 1$, there are two input that returns the same value.

Comment: For the second example aren't this two functions for the range $[-2,3]$ instead of one?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. The function is from $[-2,3]$ to $[0,1]$.

Comment: You said that there is the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{4}x+\frac{1}{2}$ for $-2 \le x \le 2$ and $f(x)=3-x$ for $2 \le x \le 3$ but this are two functions instead of the required one function for the whole range or is there a flaw?

Comment: No, I defined $f(x)$ as a function that returns $\frac{1}{4}x+\frac{1}{2}$ if (that's a very important if) $-2 \le x \le 2$ and returns $3-x$ if $2 \le x \le 3$. It is one function that is defined differently in different intervals.